# how am I supposed to do these problems any differently? (finding basis for row space)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm given two problems, which look exactly the same except the second one says "consisting of only row vectors of A". here are the problems:

[image: two problems]

on 5 II, I ended up row reducing and writing my basis for RA as {(1,0,1,0),(0,1,1,0),(0,0,0,1)}

did I write this basis correctly in number 5? Can I technically write the same answer again for number 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can state the basis of the row space in terms of column or row vectors. When you're asked to find the row vectors spanning the row space, reduce the matrix and simply take all the non-zero rows as your basis.

Comment: ok, so it seems like I did that in number 5 right? so could I just write that as my answer again in number 6?

Comment: Your answer is wrong. If you reduce you matrix correctly you will find one zero row. But yes, if your row vectors are correct then they would answer problem 5 and 6. I think problem 5 is just poorly worded and is meant to only ask you to reduce the matrix so that you can find the basis in problem 6.